# What are some sample processes that I can run in the background?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to learn what I can do from linux command to processes.

The problem is, I don't have many programs to check those commands on. I can't exactly kill bash, and putting process yes in background is a death sentence.

Since I am running on a server, I can't exactly just open a program in desktop.

Is there any notepad or calculator I could open in the background, so that it shows on the list of processes and allows me to check some options? I tried to use wget but this also doesn't seem to show up in my processes, maybe the download is too fast, I don't really get the issue with it...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `sleep 60 &` will do nothing for 60 seconds.

Comment: you can also run `yes &` and type `pkill yes` to stop it. Although you won't see what you're writing, it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `yes` in background, you can still do :

```
$ yes > /dev/null &
```

where `> /dev/null` redirects the output of the command to `/dev/null`.

Alternatively, you can run an infinite sleep :

```
$ sleep infinity &
```

which will run until killed

Answer (score 0):

You could run a script or a utility from the command line with an appended ampersand in order to cause it to run in the background, like this:

```
./script.sh &
```

You could create a simple script that does nothing but sleep and run it in the background. A sample sleeping script could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; sleep 1; done
```

Comment: You can also just directly run e.g. `sleep 60 &` to sleep for a minute in background. If you want to sleep infinitely, use `sleep infinity &`. No need to write a custom script.